# Simulation of Random Variables (Proof)

Tags: simulation

Given U is an uniform random variable on [0,1] and F is a cdf with inverse $F^{-1}$. I want to prove that $F^{-1}(U)$ has distribution F. Is the following proof correct:

$F_{X}^{-1}(u) = x$ <=> $F_{X}(x) = u$

Proof:

$F_{X}(x) = F_{U}(u)$ =>
$\int_{0}^{u} P_{u}(u)du = \int_{0}^{1} 1 du = u.$

Is this correct?

Comment: If this is for a subject, please add the homework tag.

Comment: Your assertion is the *definition* of $F_X^{-1}$.  What you need to prove is that $\Pr_U(F^{-1}(U) \le x) = F(x)$. Notice, please, that $\int_0^1 du = 1$, not $du$.

Comment: It is not for a homework. I was discussing with a friend and we were wondering, if it is possible to show it like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that the given CDF $F(\cdot)$ is a one-to-one mapping from $(-\infty,\infty)$ to $(0,1)$.  Then, the inverse function $F^{-1}$ is a one-to-one map from $(0,1)$ to
$(-\infty,\infty)$ with the property that 
if $F(x) = u$ for a given $x \in (-\infty,\infty)$, then $0 < u < 1$,
and $F^{-1}(u) = x$.

Now $X=F^{-1}(U)$ means that if on a trial of the experiment,
the uniform random variable $U$ takes on value $u \in (0,1)$, 
then $X = F^{-1}(U)$ has value $x$.  For given real number
$x$, what is the probability that $X$ has value *at most* $x$?
That is, what is $P\{X \leq x\}$? Clearly, $X$ will take one
values $x$ or smaller if and only if $U$ took on values $u$ or smaller,
where $u = F(x)$.  But, $P\{U \leq u\} = u$ since $U$ is uniformly
distributed on $(0,1)$, and so we have that
$$P\{X \leq x\} = P\{U \leq u\} = u,$$
that is, for *each* real number $x$, $P\{X \leq x\}$ which by
definition is the value of the CDF $F_X(\cdot)$ at $x$, equals
$u = F(x)$.  In short,
$$F_X(x) = P\{X\leq x\} = u = F(x) ~\text{for all}~ x \in (-\infty,\infty).$$
Thus, $X = F^{-1}(U)$ is a random variable whose CDF is $F(\cdot)$,
the CDF that we wanted $X$ to have.

Now, fix up the argument to include cases when $X$ takes on values in
a finite integral, when the inverse function is not uniquely defined,
etc.

Comment: Yes, that was my idea too..what I posted was actually my friends idea and I was all of a sudden unsure what the problem with it is. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: As @Glen_b hinted, a completely general demonstration is much simpler than this: from the definition of the inverse function, $\Pr_U(F^{-1}(U)\le x)$ = $\Pr_U(U\le F(x))$. The definition of a uniform variate states that provided $0 \le F(x) \le 1$ (which is axiomatically true for all $x$) this latter value equals $F(x)$, QED.

Comment: @whuber I know that a completely general demonstration is much simpler but over far too many years of teaching this notion, I have found that beginning students, and especially weaker students, are completely floored by the one-line proof. For many students, probability theory is the first time they have encountered things long forgotten from (or never taught or emphasized in) first-year calculus. Thus a more prolix approach works far better, and after the students gain more familiarity with the topic, the one-liner is appreciated far more.

Comment: OK, fair enough. But I would like to suggest there's pedagogical value, too, in finishing off the loquacious version with the straightforward one--or even starting with the straightforward one and then offering the rest of your answer as a gloss on it. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Start like this: Let $X = F^{-1}(U)$. Then $F_X(x) = P(X\leq x) = P(F^{-1}(U)\leq x) =...$